# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource | CORS Error

Tags: node.js, cors, cpanel

I have a Node js, React application which works well on localhost. I recently took the code to a production environment using cPanel and now, I am getting CORS errors. These cors errors only appear in requests that are not **GET** requests.
In other requests, its preflighted request passes with a 2** response, but the xhr request keeps on failing.

[image]

Below are a list of things I have done

- Used the cors package as below

  ```
  const login_router = require("./routes/loginRouter");

  const app = express();

  const cors = require("cors");

  // I have made the request with and without app.options
  app.options("*", cors())

  // allowedDomains = [Array of allowed sites] 
  // My website is listed in the array as "https://..."
  app.use(cors({ origin: allowedDomains, credentials: true }));


  app.use("/api/user/login", login_router);
  ```

I ended up with Access to XMLHttpRequest at ____ from origin ____ has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

- Added a CORS snippet in the Nodejs **.htaccess** file (in case it has anything to do with apache)

  ```
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://..."
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
  ```

It gave Access to XMLHttpRequest at ____ from origin ____ has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, https://...', but only one is allowed.

- I also tried setting the response headers manually and still, I got the same set of errors as the first trial.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my configuration was alright.
My hosting providers have some kind of generic rules that unsets the Access-Control-Allow-Origin of the response header. All I had to do was turn off that rule and it worked.

Comment: Pardon, but where did you have to go to unset the response headers?